# trying three numbers comparision with ternary operator does not work

Tags: c, comparison, conditional-operator

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3, l;

    printf("Enter any three numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);

    (n1 >= n2) ? l = n1 : ((n1 >= n3) ? l = n1 : ((n2 >= n3) ? l = n2 : l = n3));

    printf("Largest number = %d", l);
}
```

says "lvalue required as left operandof assignment"

edited:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3, lar;

    printf("Enter any three numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);

    lar = n1 >= n2 ? n1 : n2;
    lar = lar >= n3 ? lar : n3;

    printf("Largest number = %d", lar);
}
```

this one works except had to break down to 2 parts

Comment: You want `l = (n1 >= n2) ? n1 : (n1 >= n3) ? n1 : (n2 >= n3) ? n2 : n3;`

Comment: avoid using `void main() { }`, use `int main() { }`

Comment: why avoid void?

Comment: @Alex In hosted systems (PC-like systems), the format `void main()` is non-standard. You should use `int main (void)` since it's the most standard way. In freestanding systems (embedded, microcontrollers etc) then the most common form is `void main (void)`.

Comment: Also empty parenthesis `()` is obsolete style in C (unlike C++). Always type out `(void)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?:` has higher precedence than `=`. You should do:

```
better_name_than_l = (n1 >= n2) ? n1 : ((n1 >= n3) ? n1 : ((n2 >= n3) ? n2 : n3))
```

As a bonus, the code went from "very unreadable mess" to just "slightly unreadable mess".

`l` (L) is an incredibly bad name for a variable, since it looks like `1` (one) on many fonts - to the point where safety standards like MISRA C have explicitly banned `l` as a variable name.

Also, since we've already established that we hate readable code (this is for code golfing, right?) we can even drop the inner parenthesis everywhere:

```
better_name_than_l = n1 >= n2 ? n1 : n1 >= n3 ? n1 : n2 >= n3 ? n2 : n3;
```

Precedence is `>=` over `?:` over `=`.

Comment: as long as it works let it be messy. I am new to this what is code golfing?

Comment: @Alex https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ It's a form of recreational coding challenges where the aim is to use as few source code characters as possible, rather than writing code as efficient and readable as possible.